# SQL Error: aggregates not allowed in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql

I tried looking at other posts, but I'm struggling with my query, would appreciate some help and maybe a more clear explanation of what is happening in my query and I've sort of Jerry rigged it together.

```
    select *
    from custom.szp as szp
    inner join custom.szt szt
        on szp.post_id = szp.post_id 
    where szp.post_id in (
        select szt.post_id
        from custom.sstc as sstc 
        inner join custom.szt on sstc.tag_name = szt.tag_value 
        where sstc.tag_type = 'Main Tag'
        group by szt.post_id
        having count(distinct szt.tag_value) > 1
        )
    limit 100
```

Comment: Is it the  exact code that gives you an error?   Which RDBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) you use?

Comment: Usually this type of error requires a HAVING clause

Comment: Your query looks fine. Which dbms doesn't execute it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to achieve the same result.

but the SELECT * would produce problems

```
select *
from custom.szp as szp
inner join custom.szt szt
    on szp.post_id = szp.post_id 
JOIN  (
    select szt.post_id
    from custom.sstc as sstc 
    inner join custom.szt on sstc.tag_name = szt.tag_value 
    where sstc.tag_type = 'Main Tag'
    group by szt.post_id
    having count(distinct szt.tag_value) > 1
    ) t1 ON t1.post_id <> szp.post_id
limit 100
```